# React Native: Options avaible for bubble picker ui?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, react-native, animation

i need to implement a bubble picker ui for my react native app.

Example:
[[image: React Native Bubble Select]

Maybe the only similar result i found is about the Apple Music Selector:
[image]

I found results on internet like this:

1. [React Native Bubble Select](https://github.com/jesster2k10/react-native-bubble-select): Obsolete
2. [React Native Physics](https://github.com/mileung/react-native-physics): Obsolete
3. [React Native Game Engine](https://github.com/bberak/react-native-game-engine): Obsolete

I tried with emulate some animations but looks aweful. Theres some physic engine for React Native that i can implement?

I tried with Matter.js the next with something so basic but i cant see anything:

```js
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import { View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import Matter from 'matter-js';
import { GameEngine } from 'react-native-game-engine';

const CircularButtonAnimation_Screen = () => {
  const engine = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('Creating engine...');
    engine.current = Matter.Engine.create();
    console.log('Engine created:', engine.current);

    const { world } = engine.current;

    console.log('Creating world...');
    console.log('Dimension screen:', '400 x 400');

    // Crear cuerpo circular
    console.log('Creating circle...');
    const circle = Matter.Bodies.circle(200, 200, 25, {
      isStatic: true,
    });
    console.log('Círcle created:', circle);

    console.log('Adding circle in the world...');
    Matter.World.add(world, circle);

    return () => {
      console.log('Cleaning world...');
      // Matter.World.clear(world);
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <GameEngine
        style={styles.gameEngine}
        systems={[]}
        entities={{
          physics: { engine: engine.current },
        }}
      />
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: 'grey',
  },
  gameEngine: {
    flex: 1,
  },
});

export default CircularButtonAnimation_Screen;
```

This is the log:

```
 LOG  Creating world...                                                                                                                               
 LOG  Dimension screen: 400 x 400                                                                                                                     
 LOG  Creating circle...                                                                                                                              
 LOG  Círcle created: {"_original": {"density": 0.001, "friction": 0.1, "inertia": 2407.040215928269, "inverseInertia": 0.0004154479818752644, "invers
eMass": 0.5142834297505565, "mass": 1.9444530819999999, "restitution": 0}, "angle": 0, "anglePrev": 0, "angularSpeed": 0, "angularVelocity": 0, "area"
: 1944.4530819999998, "axes": [{"x": -0.9709182366411434, "y": -0.23941131501592125}, {"x": -0.8855293211163864, "y": -0.4645834924350539}, {"x": -0.7
48461108518164, "y": -0.6631786856012194}, {"x": -0.5679927261836174, "y": -0.8230335734358}, {"x": -0.35473926289412316, "y": -0.9349652696016757}, {
"x": -0.1204602009454297, "y": -0.9927181573781084}, {"x": 0.1204602009454297, "y": -0.9927181573781084}, {"x": 0.35473926289412316, "y": -0.934965269
6016757}, {"x": 0.5679927261836174, "y": -0.8230335734358}, {"x": 0.748461108518164, "y": -0.6631786856012194}, {"x": 0.8855293211163864, "y": -0.4645
834924350539}, {"x": 0.9709182366411434, "y": -0.23941131501592125}, {"x": 1, "y": 0}], "bounds": {"max": {"x": 224.818, "y": 225}, "min": {"x": 175.1
82, "y": 175}}, "chamfer": null, "circleRadius": 25, "collisionFilter": {"category": 1, "group": 0, "mask": 4294967295}, "constraintImpulse": {"angle"
: 0, "x": 0, "y": 0}, "deltaTime": 16.666666666666668, "density": Infinity, "events": null, "force": {"x": 0, "y": 0}, "friction": 1, "frictionAir": 0
.01, "frictionStatic": 0.5, "id": 1, "inertia": Infinity, "inverseInertia": 0, "inverseMass": 0, "isSensor": false, "isSleeping": false, "isStatic": t
rue, "label": "Circle Body", "mass": Infinity, "motion": 0, "parent": [Circular], "parts": [[Circular]], "plugin": {}, "position": {"x": 200, "y": 200
}, "positionImpulse": {"x": 0, "y": 0}, "positionPrev": {"x": 200, "y": 200}, "render": {"fillStyle": "#14151f", "lineWidth": 1, "opacity": 1, "sprite
": {"xOffset": 0.5, "xScale": 1, "yOffset": 0.5, "yScale": 1}, "strokeStyle": "#555", "visible": true}, "restitution": 0, "sleepCounter": 0, "sleepThr
eshold": 60, "slop": 0.05, "speed": 0, "timeScale": 1, "torque": 0, "totalContacts": 0, "type": "body", "velocity": {"x": 0, "y": 0}, "vertices": [{"b
ody": [Circular], "index": 0, "isInternal": false, "x": 224.818, "y": 203.013}, {"body": [Circular], "index": 1, "isInternal": false, "x": 223.375, "y
": 208.865}, {"body": [Circular], "index": 2, "isInternal": false, "x": 220.575, "y": 214.202}, {"body": [Circular], "index": 3, "isInternal": false, 
"x": 216.578, "y": 218.713}, {"body": [Circular], "index": 4, "isInternal": false, "x": 211.618, "y": 222.136}, {"body": [Circular], "index": 5, "isIn
ternal": false, "x": 205.983, "y": 224.274}, {"body": [Circular], "index": 6, "isInternal": false, "x": 200, "y": 225}, {"body": [Circular], "index": 
7, "isInternal": false, "x": 194.017, "y": 224.274}, {"body": [Circular], "index": 8, "isInternal": false, "x": 188.382, "y": 222.136}, {"body": [Circ
ular], "index": 9, "isInternal": false, "x": 183.422, "y": 218.713}, {"body": [Circular], "index": 10, "isInternal": false, "x": 179.425, "y": 214.202
}, {"body": [Circular], "index": 11, "isInternal": false, "x": 176.625, "y": 208.865}, {"body": [Circular], "index": 12, "isInternal": false, "x": 175
.182, "y": 203.013}, {"body": [Circular], "index": 13, "isInternal": false, "x": 175.182, "y": 196.987}, {"body": [Circular], "index": 14, "isInternal
": false, "x": 176.625, "y": 191.135}, {"body": [Circular], "index": 15, "isInternal": false, "x": 179.425, "y": 185.798}, {"body": [Circular], "index
": 16, "isInternal": false, "x": 183.422, "y": 181.287}, {"body": [Circular], "index": 17, "isInternal": false, "x": 188.382, "y": 177.864}, {"body": 
[Circular], "index": 18, "isInternal": false, "x": 194.017, "y": 175.726}, {"body": [Circular], "index": 19, "isInternal": false, "x": 200, "y": 175},
 {"body": [Circular], "index": 20, "isInternal": false, "x": 205.983, "y": 175.726}, {"body": [Circular], "index": 21, "isInternal": false, "x": 211.6
18, "y": 177.864}, {"body": [Circular], "index": 22, "isInternal": false, "x": 216.578, "y": 181.287}, {"body": [Circular], "index": 23, "isInternal":
 false, "x": 220.575, "y": 185.798}, {"body": [Circular], "index": 24, "isInternal": false, "x": 223.375, "y": 191.135}, {"body": [Circular], "index":
 25, "isInternal": false, "x": 224.818, "y": 196.987}]}                                                                                               
 LOG  Adding circle in the world...
```

**What i´m expecting?**
Let me know how implement a bubble picker, or lead me what physic engine are available and updated for the most new of React native.

Working with:

1. React Native: 0.73.5
2. React-Native-Cli: 11.3.7
3. matter-js: 0.19.0
4. react-native-game-engine: 1.2.0

Thanks for any help